# What is the limit of $(x_n/x_{n+1})^n$?

Tags: limits, analysis

My question is as followed.

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ satisfies:
$0<x_1<\pi$,
and $x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ for $n=1,2,\dotsc$

Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)^{1/x_n^2}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\right)^n$.

---

I have proved $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$.
Thus
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)^{1/x_n^2}
&= \lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x\to0} \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2} \ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right) \\
&= \exp\left[ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\sin x-x}{x}\right)}{x^2} \right] \\
&= \exp\left( \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3} \right) \\
&= \exp\left( \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2} \right) \\
&= \exp\left( \lim_{x\to0} \frac{-\sin x}{6x} \right) \\
&= \exp(-1/6).
\end{align}

However, I failed to figure it out how to calculate the second limit.

Comment: As a hint, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867122/justify-if-x-gt-0-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-cdot-overbrace-sin-sin-cdo/2867164#2867164. ;P